Spring Boot 3 with JPA, PostgreSQL, large data query very slow
We have a data structure in PostgreSQL 16 which is moderately complex, I have a simplified diagram showing the join columns here:

The 3 SURVEY tables on the top left are exceptions because they are not joined with foreign key, rather we have a SURVEY_ID column which can point to the ID of any of this 3 SURVEY tables (this is due to historic reasons, another column in the SURVEY_INPUT table decides which of these 3 to use). SURVEY_INPUT table also has the same SURVEY_ID column, which is not present here.
Here are the row counts:

SURVEY_INPUT: 160K
SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_ID: 110K
SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_DATE: 68K
SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_CHARACTERISTICS: 355K
SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_PARTY: 400K
SURVEY_RESPONSE: 29K
SURVEY_RESPONSE_DATA: 76K

When these tables were designed there were no such requirements, but now we are looking at some specific reports which are ungodly slow. It must be filtered by the highlighted columns. At the moment we have maybe 1 week's data in these tables and the report can take 10 minutes to load, and we need to support 3 month's data... What I'm basically looking for as step 1 is to whether focus on the application side queries or the database performance... In our original implementation some entity relationships were eager in JPA, some were lazy, which resulted in lots and lots of simple and quick queries being launched, which ultimately resulted in the long execution. Now the application developer has did some magic, set everything to be eager and now JPA created a monster query to get all the data with all the filtering in a single step. This is now faster, but still it can take anywhere from 3 to 6 minutes, depending on selected time range. I tried to work on this large query as well, added some indexes on the highlighted colors as well as all join columns, but had minimal impact. I'll put this large query here, this was fully generated by JPA:
SELECT S1_0.ID,
    D1_0.ID,
    D1_0.CREATE_DATE,
    D1_0.DELETED,
    D1_0.ENABLED,
    D1_0.FILL_COUNT,
    D1_0.IS_CHAT,
    D1_0.LAST_MODIFY_DATE,
    D1_0.NAME,
    D1_0.SURVEY_JSON,
    D1_0.THEME_ID,
    D1_0.UNIQUE_ID,
    S1_0.RESPONSE_DATE,
    S9_0.ID,
    S9_0.AIFO_CAMPAIGN_ID,
    S9_0.CATEGORY,
    S9_0.CREATE_DATE,
    S9_0.DELETED,
    S9_0.EMAIL_SUBJECT,
    S9_0.ENABLED,
    S9_0.FILL_COUNT,
    S9_0.LAST_MODIFY_DATE,
    S9_0.NAME,
    S9_0.REMINDER_EMAIL_SUBJECT,
    S9_0.SURVEY_JSON,
    S9_0.THEME_ID,
    S9_0.UNIQUE_ID,
    S2_0.ID,
    S2_0.CREATE_TIME,
    S2_0.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    S2_0.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_OBJECT_ID,
    S2_0.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    S2_0.EVENT_TIME,
    S2_0.INDIVIDUAL_NUMBER,
    S2_0.INDIVIDUAL_OBJECT_ID,
    S2_0.KAFKA_TOPIC,
    S2_0.PHONENUMBER,
    S2_0.PROCESSING_HOST,
    S2_0.SMS_CHAIN_CURRENT_INDEX,
    S2_0.STATUS,
    S2_0.SURVEY_CHANNEL,
    S2_0.SURVEY_ID,
    S6_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID,
    S6_0.ID,
    S6_0.REFERRED_TYPE,
    S6_0.REFERRED_VALUE,
    S3_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID,
    S3_0.ID,
    S3_0.REFERRED_TYPE,
    S3_0.REFERRED_VALUE,
    S5_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID,
    S5_0.ID,
    S5_0.REFERRED_TYPE,
    S5_0.REFERRED_VALUE,
    S4_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID,
    S4_0.ID,
    S4_0.REFERRED_TYPE,
    S4_0.REFERRED_VALUE,
    S2_0.SURVEY_LANGUAGE,
    S2_0.SURVEY_SEND_TIME,
    S2_0.SURVEY_TOUCHPOINT,
    S2_0.SURVEY_TYPE,
    S2_0.UNIQUE_ID,
    S7_0.SURVEY_RESPONSE_ID,
    S7_0.ID,
    S7_0.NORMALIZED_SMS_RESPONSE,
    S7_0.ORIG_SMS_RESPONSE,
    S7_0.QUESTION_ID,
    S7_0.QUESTION_REPORT_ID,
    S7_0.QUESTION_TYPE,
    S7_0.RESPONSE,
    S7_0.RESPONSE_DATE,
    S8_0.SURVEY_RESPONSE_ID,
    S8_0.QUESTION_TYPE,
    S8_0.ID,
    S8_0.NORMALIZED_SMS_RESPONSE,
    S8_0.ORIG_SMS_RESPONSE,
    S8_0.QUESTION_ID,
    S8_0.QUESTION_REPORT_ID,
    S8_0.RESPONSE,
    S8_0.RESPONSE_DATE,
    S10_0.ID,
    S10_0.CREATE_DATE,
    S10_0.DELETED,
    S10_0.ENABLED,
    S10_0.FILL_COUNT,
    S10_0.LAST_MODIFY_DATE,
    S10_0.NAME,
    S10_0.UNIQUE_ID
FROM SURVEY.SURVEY_RESPONSE S1_0
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY1 D1_0 ON D1_0.ID = S1_0.SURVEY_ID
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY_INPUT S2_0 ON S2_0.ID = S1_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_DATE S3_0 ON S2_0.ID = S3_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_PARTY S4_0 ON S2_0.ID = S4_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_ID S5_0 ON S2_0.ID = S5_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY_INPUT_RELATED_CHARACTERISTICS S6_0 ON S2_0.ID = S6_0.SURVEY_INPUT_ID
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY_RESPONSE_DATA S7_0 ON S1_0.ID = S7_0.SURVEY_RESPONSE_ID
AND (S7_0.QUESTION_TYPE = 'NORMAL')
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY_RESPONSE_DATA S8_0 ON S1_0.ID = S8_0.SURVEY_RESPONSE_ID
AND (S8_0.QUESTION_TYPE <> 'NORMAL')
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY2 S9_0 ON S9_0.ID = S1_0.SURVEY_ID
LEFT JOIN SURVEY.SURVEY3 S10_0 ON S10_0.ID = S1_0.SURVEY_ID
WHERE S1_0.RESPONSE_DATE BETWEEN '2024-05-31T22:00:00'::timestamp AND '2024-06-03T21:59:59'::timestamp
    AND S2_0.SURVEY_TOUCHPOINT in ('touchpoint1', 'touchpoint2', 'touchpoint3')
    AND S2_0.SURVEY_TYPE in ('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
    AND S2_0.SURVEY_CHANNEL in ('channel1', 'channel2', 'channel3')
ORDER BY S1_0.RESPONSE_DATE ASC,
    S7_0.ID ASC

The reason for this monster query is that it has to be displayed in a table in a complex way too... e.g. some SURVEY_RESPONSE_DATA fields where QUESTION_TYPE <> 'NORMAL' have to be displayed in separate columns, while where QUESTION_TYPE = 'NORMAL' will be combined into a single column as comma separated list, so JPA joins this table twice because of it.
What would be the better approach here, without completely restructuring the DB, for which I will not get the budget?

Measure. Measure which part is slow, is it the query? Is it the mapping? Is it hibernate processing. I also don't get the join with the where, QUESTION_TYPE is part of the result already, do some smart mapping on the java side instead of a double join. ALso making everything eager is a bad idea as well, as this will lead to a massive result. However the important part here is measure and optimize the parts that are slow.

The query, 100%. Based on the logs, after the query was ready, the Excel output generation in Java took a further 30 seconds, but otherwise everything was fast on the application side. I was just wondering how to resolve it. Yes setting everything to eager resulted in the monster query which is just a huge cross join of everything with everything, lots of NULL fields.

What do you concern as the query was ready? The actual SQL, or the SQL including the mapping and all other things hibernate does (as I suspect you mean the latter, not the former). Also do you first collect all results and the write the excel, then why? Just stream the results instead of first loading your whole database in-memory and then do the processing. Also as stated I don't get the joins that are generated (you must have some clauses in there) why is that even there instead of you doing that in code?

Another thing to check is did you set a jdbc fetch size? Default is 10, which means after 10 rows it needs to go back to the DB server to fetch the next 10 rows. Now unless you are on the same machine as the DB is, this involves networking etc. Increase the JDBC fetch-size to a more reasonable size, something like 1000. Set the query to read-only as well.

So I actually doubt the query is slow, I suspect that if you paste this into a SQL tool it will execute pretty fast. I suspect that due to your model that most of the time is spent inside Hibernate mapping that massive result to entities.

I think when we see it getting done in the application it is after the hibernate processing is also done, basically we have a log message before and after we call the query through the repository class. But we took the JPA generated query from the logs and ran it natively in the DB, and it also ran for roughly the same amount of time as in the application. As for why not streaming it... I guess we implemented it in the naive way originally, and now we have fallen on our faces with the large data size

I stand corrected, at least partially :) The query is quite fast, so is the processing in Java, what seems to be slow is the network... Query execution time on the server is in seconds, but I see the result in minutes. After removing a bunch of unnecessary columns, including some TEXT columns holding large JSON texts, the full execution time is now around 30 seconds, including downloading all the data.

Increase the fetch size as I suggested that will/should improve more as it will reduce the round trips.

Based on documentation and other questions here on SO, PostgreSQL will by default fetch all records. Oracle limits it to 10, but not PostgreSQL. So I think we're okay on that front.
